# Does this line: return acc + cur.length; automatically sets the new acc?

Tags: javascript, reduce

Here is my code, it basically limits the words of a title.

I wonder why `return acc + cur.length;` automatically sets the new value of `acc` without the need of storing it into a new variable.

Thank you so much!

```
const limitRecipeTitle = (title, limit = 17) => {
    const newTitle = [];
    if (title.length > limit) {
        title.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => {
            if (acc + cur.length <= limit) {
                newTitle.push(cur);
            }
            return acc + cur.length;
        }, 0);
        return `${newTitle.join(' ')} ...`;
    }
    return title;
};
```

Comment: yes, that's how reduce works

Comment: [_"The accumulator accumulates the callback's return values. It is the accumulated value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback, or `initialValue`, if supplied"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*" I wonder why this line: return acc + cur.length; automatically sets the new value of acc without the need of storing it into a new const."*

You're passing the callback function to `.reduce()`. The `.reduce()` method internally calls the function you provided and stores its return value.

These calls are happening in a loop, so callback invocadtion in the next iteration of the loop gets the value you returned from the previous iteration.

Here's a ***very*** simplified version of a `.reduce` method.

```js
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, acc) {
  var i = 0;
  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    acc = this[0];
    i = 1;
  }
  while (i < this.length) {
    // The provided callback gets invoked with the current
    // value of `acc`, and then overwrites `acc` with the 
    // return value so that the next iteration gets passed
    // that new value.
    acc = callback(acc, this[i], i, this);
    i++;
  }
  return acc;
};
```